# Downsampling a postgresql table

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, downsampling

I have a really simple database model, two tables : **object** and **data**, linked with an 1:n relationship.

Every minute, for each **object**, a new **data** is saved. The interesting attributes are : *object_id* (int), *created_at* (timestamp) and *value* (varchar). *Object_id* and *created_at* are used as composite PK)

My problem is that it generate way too much data. I'm trying to find an effective way to downsample the **data** periodically. What I need to do :

- don't touch the X last weeks
- keep only one value per Y minutes for each object.

I'm not so familiar with plpgsql and I strongly suspect that there is something smart to do with date_trunc and/or my composite PK containing that date...

pgsql  9.4.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delete from data
where 
    (
    -- year of `created_at` is less then current year
    extract('year' from created_at) < extract('year' from current_date)
    or
    -- year of `created_at` is equal to current year
    extract('year' from created_at) = extract('year' from current_date)
    and
    -- number of week of `created_at` is less then current week by 3 or more
    extract('week' from current_date) - extract('week' from created_at) >= 3
    )
and 
    -- number of minutes is not a multiple of 10
    extract('minute' from created_at)::int % 10 <> 0
```

Comment: Doesn't this mean at beginning of year, records less than 3 weeks older will be erased?